# Можно ли сделать список раскрывающийся и кнопку показать всё/скрыть только с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать список раскрывающийся и кнопку показать всё/скрыть только с помощью css?

[image] [image]

Я не разобралась с тем, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку снизу раскрывался весь список. Задала блоку `overflow:hidden;`, а при нажатии `max-height:auto;` и `overflow: visible;` Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так

https://jsfiddle.net/zzrboku5/

Comment: http://codepen.io/ekrof/pen/YqmXdQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно с помощью чекбокса и label

```css
ul li{ list-style-type: none; }
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #464646;
}
body{ background:#fff; }
.catalog_item:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 cursor: pointer;
 border-color: transparent
}
.catalog_item{
 height: 406px;
 width: 266px;
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid #6d87b4;
 margin: 50px 30px 0 0;
 position: relative;
}
.catalog_item>div{ margin: 18px 0 0 23px; }
.catalog_item>p{
    font: 20px RobotoBold;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}
.catalog_item div>ul{
   margin-top: 20px;
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.catalog_item div ul li{ clear: both; }
.open_list:active .catalog_item div>ul>ul, .open_list:focus .catalog_item div>ul>ul, .open_list:visited .catalog_item div>ul>ul{
 overflow: visible !important;
 max-height: auto;
}
.catalog_item ul ul{
 margin-left: 30px;
 display: none;
}
.catalog_item ul ul li{
 list-style-type: disc;
 color: #f7cac9;
}
.catalog_item div>ul>li:hover>a{ color: #f7cac9; }
.catalog_item div>ul>li:hover:before{ color: #f7cac9; }
.catalog_item div>ul>li:before {
    content:  "—";
    position: relative;
    color: #6d87b4;
}
.catalog_item div>ul>li>a{
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.catalog_item .open_list{
   text-decoration: underline;
    color: #6d87b4;
}
#trigger {display: none}
label {cursor: pointer;}
.hide--list {display: none}

#trigger:checked + .catalog_item
{height: auto;}
#trigger:checked + .catalog_item > div > ul
{height: auto}
#trigger:checked + .catalog_item .hide--list {display: block;}
#trigger:checked + .catalog_item .show--list {display: none}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
  <div class="catalog_item">
  <p>Мебель для спальни</p>
  <div>
    <img src="http://billsupholsterynj.com/communities/5/000/001/766/635//images/9638816.png" alt""/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Кровати</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Двухъярусные</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Деревянные</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Из ДСП</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Из МДФ</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Металлические</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Подиумные</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Матрасы</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Безпружинные</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Пружинные</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Наматрасники</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Топперы</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Футоны</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Комоды</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Подушки</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Покрывала</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Полки</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Постельное белье</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Раскладушки</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Спальни</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Трюмо и туалетные столы</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Тумбы</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Тумбы прикроватные</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Шкафы распашные</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Шкафы-купе</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <label for="trigger" class="open_list">
      <span class="show--list">Показать все</span>
      <span class="hide--list">Скрыть</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```